# React-router, Switch and Redux: Route inexplicably not rendering, no error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

So, I'm trying to create a simple chat app with React, the app has an authentication workflow, and the logged in user is stored in a Redux store. I have a basic routing set up in my App.js (react-router v4), which ensures that only users that are logged in get to the actual chat screen. If the user is not logged in, they will be redirected to login screen. Now, I also want to persist the session (I'm using passport.js to handle session cookies in the backend), so that if the user that already logged in presses F5 and refresh the page for example, we won't have to go through the login process again. This is done by dispatching a thunk action (getLoggedUser()), that will simply check that the cookie we have in the browser is still accepted by the server, and then reload the user object to the Redux store (the prop loggedInUser).

This is where the weirdness ensues. My login and session authentication pipeline already works perfectly as it should, but when I refresh the page after logging in, the routes inside the router Switch do not render anything at all. I have tested that the right Switch actually gets rendered, but somehow the Route inside that switch will not get rendered. And this ONLY happens when refreshing after a successful login. I'm completely at loss as to what is causing this. I have tried using the withRouter middleware from react-router package, it did nothing. I even tried delaying the call to getLoggedUser() in the constructor to make sure that there was no race condition of some kind, but that didn't help either.

Here's the code for the App.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';

import MainChat from './components/MainChat';
import Login from './components/Login';
import { getLoggedUser } from './actions/';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.getLoggedUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App__container">
          {this.props.loggedInUser ? (
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/chat" component={MainChat} />
              <Redirect exact path="/" to="/chat" />
            </Switch>
          ) : (
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Redirect path="/" to="/login" />
            </Switch>
          )}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getLoggedUser: () => dispatch(getLoggedUser())
});

export default connect(
  state => ({ loggedInUser: state.auth.loggedInUser }),
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you having webpack?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm building my app on create-react-app

Comment: Which React version are you using, if it's v4 you have to use react-router-dom.

Comment: It's the latest React version, and I'm using react-router-dom.

Comment: Out of the blue, setting the routers 'location' may help.  Does the Route render if you pass it a child component?

Answer (score 0):

try puting your getLoggedUser() action trigger inside componentDidMount()  function instead of your constructor as follow:

```
ComponentDidMount(){
    this.props.getLoggedUser()
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried that and other lifecycle methods too, it doesn't help.